# How to apply animation for one specific modifier change only?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

How to only apply `.animation` to `.offset` while keeping other modifier change not affected by it. Adding `.animation` after offset would also animate the font size changing.

[image]

```
// Main view
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        VStack {
            DynamicText()
        }
        .frame(height: geo.size.height)
        .offset(y: self.viewModel.offset ? 5.0 : 0)
        .animation(.default)
    }
}

// DynamicText view
var body: some View {
    return GeometryReader { geo in
        VStack {
            Text("Foo")
                .font(
                    .system(size: geo.size.height * 0.95, weight: .regular, design: .monospaced))
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.05)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .foregroundColor(Color("primary"))
        }
        .frame(height: geo.size.height)
    }
}
```

Also tried putting `.animation(nil)` for modifiers above have no intention for animating, however, it also stops the offset from animating. Because of the `ZStack` contains different conditional rendered `DynamicText` the animation modifier also applies the fade-in-out transition between the content changes which is something I want to avoid.

```
// Main view
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        VStack {
            DynamicText()
        }
        .animation(nil)
        .frame(height: geo.size.height)
        .offset(y: self.viewModel.offset ? 5.0 : 0)
        .animation(.default)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.animation(nil)` on `DynamicText()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The provided snapshot is not testable, so just a thought - try to limit animation to offset value explicitly, like

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        VStack {
            DynamicText()
        }
        .frame(height: geo.size.height)
        .offset(y: self.viewModel.offset ? 5.0 : 0)
        .animation(.default, value: self.viewModel.offset)     // << here !!
    }
}
```