# When I use withAnimation in the Model, no animation happens, why?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swiftui

here is my `ViewModel`

```
import SwiftUI

class SetGameVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var model: SetGame = SetGame()
    
    var cards: Array<SetGame.Card> {
        model.cards
    }
   
    func selectCard(card: SetGame.Card) {
        model.selectCard(card: card)
    }
    
    func dealCards() {
        model.dealMoreCards()
    }

    func reset() {
        model = SetGame()
    }
}
```

and `Model`

```
import SwiftUI

struct SetGame {
    var cards: Array<Card>

 mutating func selectCard(card: Card) -> Bool {
        ...
       withAnimation {
        dealMoreCards()
       }
       ...
   }
}
```

If I use `withAnimation` in `ViewModle` or `View` then animation happens as expected, else if I use `withAnimation` in the `Model` which wraps some changes, `View` still reflect those changes, but no animation happens.

Comment: When you change a property in a struct, you'll get a new one. I think that's the reason you don't see any animations.

Comment: Does the `mutating` function still create a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in view model

```
func selectCard(card: SetGame.Card) {
    withAnimation {                       // << here !!
       model.selectCard(card: card)
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this will work, but sometimes I need some state changes animated and some others not and all these changes happens when invoke the `selectCard` method, so I want to wrap those changes in the `Model`

Comment: for that purpose you have to use `.animation(..., value: <your state here>)` modifier

Comment: What the `value` should be, a `@State` or `Property`, I have tried both animation always run just like value always changing, but actualy it's not.

Comment: See this for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/63771023/12299030